# I want to know about WPF binding Textbox line down

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox

I am trying to make a logger system with WPF in xaml. I made the below biding code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="10,194,0,0"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Height="51"
           Width="366"
           Text="{Binding LogView,
                          Source={StaticResource logViewModel},
                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The Binding text is working correctly, but in the textbox, string is updated only on the first line in the textbox. The string should be updated on the next line,
and I can't use append string like the below code because I will be parsing Character(ex. D,E,I) and then changing the string color:

```
mLogViewStr+=value;
```

help me please...

logViewModel :

```
 namespace StretcherUI.Device
    {
        class LogViewModel : ILogHandler,
                             INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            static string savePath = @"d:\log.txt";
            const int logListSize = 500;
            public LogViewModel()
            {
                Logger.sLogHandler = this;
            }


            private string mLogViewStr;
            public string LogView
            {
                get { return mLogViewStr; }
                set
                {
                    mLogViewStr = value;               
                }
            }

            protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                                    this,
                                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            public void onLog(string logFmt, params object[] arg)
            {
                LogView = string.Format(logFmt, arg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not update, or does not show at all lines after first one?

Comment: Hello, it update but only in first line..i want text update at first line and then next text update at second line..third line..

Comment: Show us your ViewModel. It's hard to understand without more code to work with.

Comment: You binded your textbox.Text to logView, so it shows whatever you have in the model. Check if the logView is actually what you think it is.

Comment: private string mLogViewStr;
        public string LogView
        {
            get { return mLogViewStr; }
            set
            {
                mLogViewStr = value;               
            }
        }

Comment: i will upload my viewmodel..

Comment: @Myoungjae.yiYi I guss you mean, that your binding works only once, and when later you update value of mLogViewStr, nothing updates? This is because your binding is incorrect. You should use [Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification))

Comment: i uploade my view model..

Comment: iLogHandler is gain log string from c# code..

Answer (score 2):

you should call **OnPropertyChanged** in your public setter, that way WPF view can understand that it has pending update

```C#
  public string LogView
            {
                get { return mLogViewStr; }
                set
                {
                    mLogViewStr = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LogView");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Binding from model to view work only if you notify View. So in order to notify view, model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged (which you did) and call PropertyChanged every time bound property changed (which you missed).
Just modify your code like this:

```
public string LogView {
  get {
    return mLogViewStr;
  }
  set {
    mLogViewStr = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LogView))             
  }
}
```